# Find one non-example $A \in M_{4x4}$ s.t. $ A^4=I \ne A^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Im trying to work this problem that and I'm stuck on this one part of it. I just need to find one non-example $A \in M_{4x4}$ s.t. $A^4=I\ne A^3$

Im assuming it may have somthing to do with even/odd powers

Comment: You assume well.

Comment: For example, a $4\times 4$ nonidentity matrix $A$ whose square is the identity will satisfy this condition.

Comment: If your task is to find an matrix such that $A^4=I\neq A^3$ you may think of rotations which take the form $\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \cos(\alpha)& -\sin(\alpha) \\
 \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) \\
\end{array}
\right)$ and of course extend it to $n=4$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest (nontrivial - see comments) example is the following matrix that permutes the columns: 
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
In order to get the identity you have to take $A^4$ and thus permuting the columns 4 times.

Comment: Even simpler is $A = -I$

Comment: Indeed! I don't know why, but I assumed that we needed also $A$ and $A^2$ different from the identity :)

Comment: I'm assuming that was what the intended question was.... otherwise it's a tad simple

Comment: @Mathmo123, would this still be true if F is a field?

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: The question I am working on deals with fields. I did not mention that above. Though my knowledge is still very basic, I wasnt sure if that mattered here.

Comment: So you mean if $\mathbb F$ is a field, and $a^4 = 1 \ne a^3$? In a field it's even easier as we have inverses. $a^4 = a^3 \iff a^3(a-1) = 0 \iff a = 1 \text{ or } a^3 = 0 \iff a = 0 \text{ or }  a = 1$. So any element with $a^4 = 1$ and $a \ne 0,1$ will do... so if char $\mathbb F > 2$ then -1 will work

Answer (score 0):

Note that $i^4 = 1$, so let $\hat{A} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and then let $A = \begin{pmatrix} \hat{A} & 0 \\ 0 & \hat{A}\end{pmatrix}$.